# Casperjs script returns null in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

I am a new bee in casperjs and phantomjs world. 
I am getting null from script whenever I run from PHP script while I got response in cmd.

> This is php script from where I called casperjs script named Test.js

```
<?php

    putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=C:/phantomjs/bin");
    putenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH");

    $response=null;
    $response=exec('C:/casperjs/bin C:/Test.js');
    if ($response != null) {
        echo("Null Response");
    }
    else{
        echo("Response : " . $response );
    } ?>
```

> This is Test.js. A casperjs script

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
verbose: false,
logLevel: "debug",
pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false,
    loadPlugins: false,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.0'
} });
casper.start('https://www.google.co.in/', function(){
    this.echo("From Script",'INFO')
});
casper.run();
```

> As you can see I have installed phantom and casperjs in c: and I have already set environment variable for both 
>   For phantom Env. variable - C:\phantomjs\bin\
>   For Casper Env. variable - C:\casperjs\bin

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're getting exec's response incorrect, please fix: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP should look like this:

```
$response=null;
exec('C:/casperjs/bin C:/Test.js',$response);
```

@Vaviloff posted a link to the docs page.  I've often found PHP's docs lacking in clarity, IMHO,, exec() is a case in point.  Here is what it shows:

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

If you read further down you'll see that the string it returns is, at best, the last line of something.  If you want to test the response, you need to init a var and then references as a 'callback' var (so to speak) for the exec command to write back into.

You can also try and cheat with backticks and setting our ENV vars there (or setting them at the user scope.